# Qual é a origem de «ginga»?

Tags: etimologia, girias

No norte de Portugal, mais especificamente em Famalicão, usa-se a palavra «ginga» com o significado de bicicleta.

Fui ver no dicionário e aparece como palavra de Moçambique:

> #### gin·ga
>
> (derivação regressiva de gingar) substantivo feminino
>
> 1. Espécie de remo que, apoiado num encaixe sobre a popa, faz andar a embarcação.
> 2. Movimento do corpo de um lado para outro. = MENEIO
> 3. [Brasil]  Caneco, munido de longo cabo, que serve para baldear o caldo de uma tacha para outra nos engenhos de bangué.
> 4. [Moçambique]  Bicicleta.
>
> "Ginga", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Ginga [consultado em
>   03-01-2017].

O que eu queria saber é se em mais algum ponto de Portugal ou no Brasil tem esse significado e qual a origem da palavra?

Comment: No Brasil, significa movimento do corpo. Tem qual significado??

Comment: @Lambie como assim qual o significado?

Comment: Aqui no Brasil, nunca ouvi "ginga" ser usado com outro significado além de "movimento do corpo de um lado para o outro", mas não se restringindo só a corpo, como por exemplo *"Pra dançar bem, tem que ter ginga no pé"*. Tem também "gingado", que é um pouco mais comum.

Comment: O que me parece mais provável é a palavra ter ido daqui para lá, e lá ter-se popularizado. O [Priberam também dá *mata-bicho*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mata-bicho) como palavra de Moçambique e Angola, mas isso era um termo usado já pelos meus avós aqui em Portugal.

Comment: A *Órbita*, fabricante de bicicletas de Águeda, teve um [modelo chamado *Ginga*](http://classicoslobo.blogspot.pt/2012/05/upgrade-da-orbita-ginga.html). Parece coisa dos anos 70 (a empresa foi fundada em 1971).

Comment: Ter ginga no Brasil é saber dançar no ritmo e no molejo da música. Mas pode ser também "saber se virar em situações imprevistas".

Answer (score 1):

Ginga como bicicleta parece muito regional, não acredito que alguém conseguirá responder completamente a esta pergunta, de todo modo, no Brasil não só não constam em alguns dicionários, como nunca ouvi, nem em grandes centros, nem no interior.

Algumas definições em outros dicionários onde não consta a definição para bicicleta:

http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/ginga

http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=ginga

https://www.dicio.com.br/pesquisa.php?q=ginga

Answer (score 0):

Para se manter numa "ginga" (bicicleta) é necessário equilíbrio e destreza, portanto, a palavra pode ter tido o significado expandido para outras situações.

Comment: Leonardo, bem-vindo à comunidade. Podes explicar-te melhor. Não compreendo como é que a tua resposta explica a origem de *ginga*, que é o que se pergunta.